# Find unused properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, static-analysis, properties-file

How can I find unused properties in a Spring Boot project.

The project is only using static property access (mostly via `@ConfigurationProperties`, but also `@Value` and `@Conditional` annotations etc.)

Idea sometimes warns about unused properties, but it doesn't take into account some usage, e.g. in `@Conditional` expressions.

More importantly Idea does this for a single property at a time. I need something that can run on a whole project and list all unused properties.